# iOS Guided Access mode breaks HTML <select>

Tags: ios, ipad

I have a web site built as a web app that contains a single 'select' menu. The menu works fine and the options are displayed when viewed in a browser including Mobile Safari on an iPad.

However viewing the web app with Guided Mode enabled (http://support.apple.com/kb/HT5509?viewlocale=en_US&locale=en_US) which prevents access to some iPad features, the  tag stops working and won't open. A regular link using the 'a href' tag still works though.

Does anyone know why this particular tag is not working?

Answer (score 1):

I've run into this same issue. It appears to be an iOS bug.

jQuery Mobile had a bug reported for this issue here: https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/issues/6806

They solved it by coding around it, using hidden divs that are enabled by Javascript (See their [custom select menu examples](http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.2/selectmenu-custom/#&ui-state=dialog)).